# Как быстро загрузить содержимое ворд документа в richtextbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, docx, richtextbox

Имеется следующий код который работает, но загрузка в richtextbox происходит довольно долго (от 5 до 10 секунд). Так же имеется проблема с закрытием этого документа. Ведь даже если закрыть приложение документы которые использовались для чтения не закрываются.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordObject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        object File = @path; //Путь к файлу записанный в переменную
        object nullobject = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordobject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        wordobject.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document docs = wordObject.Documents.Open(ref File, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
        docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
        docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
        richTextBox1.Paste();
        docs.Close(ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
        wordObject.Quit(); //По идее здесь документ должен закрываться, но ничего подобного.
```

Уже недели 2 пытаюсь хоть что то найти, но всё никак. Буду благодарен если поможете решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запуск и закрытие Word - дело не быстрое, даже в автоматическом режиме. Единственное, что я у вас нашел - это то что вы запускаете 2 экземпляра Word, при чем один закрываете, а второй - нет. Обратите внимание на 2 переменные `wordObject` и `wordobject`. Как я понял, это опечатка.

Далее, чтобы не "морозить" ваше приложение, пока Word думает, я вынес обработку в отдельный поток. Работает немного быстрее, чем ваш вариант, и в диспетчере больше не остается запущенного ворда. Все закрывается как надо. У меня 2-3 секунды вставка идет.

```cs
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            object file = @path;
            object nullobject = Missing.Value;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordObject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
            {
                DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone
            };
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document docs = wordObject.Documents.Open(ref file, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
            docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
            docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
            this.Invoke((Action)(() => richTextBox1.Paste()));
            docs.Close(ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
            wordObject.Quit();
        });
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Через `Interop` быстрее вряд-ли получится.

Comment: Небольшая но разница есть. Благодарю за хороший ответ.

Comment: Как очистить буфер? Текст из документа при загрузке копируется в него.

Comment: @BrW Как ворд закрывается, оно вычищаться должно по идее, а так `Clipboard.Clear()` (только не делайте это внутри `Task.Run()`). Либо попробуйте добавить в это решение `ref readonly` из ответа от Bulson. Read Only может влиять на сохранение вордом содержимого буфера.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так, может будет быстрее

```
private void ButtonOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_openFileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK
            || _openFileDialog.FileName.Length == 0)
            return;

        //открываем word & document
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word
            = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        word.Visible = false;
        object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object path = _openFileDialog.FileName;
        object readOnly = true;
        Document document = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss,
            ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
            ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
            ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

        //имя и путь ко временному файлу
        string tempFile = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
        //сохраняем во временный файл в формате RTF
        document.SaveAs2(tempFile, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatRTF);

        //закрываем документ и word
        document.Close(ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
        document = null;
        word.Quit(ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
        word = null;

        //загружаем из временного файла данные
        _richTextBoxOutput.LoadFile(tempFile);
        //удаляем временный файл
        System.IO.File.Delete(tempFile);
    }
```

Comment: Протестил, либо тоже самое, либо медленнее.

Comment: @aepot ну ворду нужно время загрузиться, открыть документ... у меня на 5-ти страничный документ уходит где-то навскидку 2-3 сек.

Comment: @Bulson к сожалению разницы незаметно)
Единственное что изменилось это лишний гемор с добавлением в юзинг строки, и немного правок в других строках. Однако всё равно спасибо за затраченное время.